# Changing input value using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've been looking for a reason why this doesn't work, but I can't find one.  In my asp.net application I create a a bunch of hidden inputs in c# and then try to modify them in javascript before I call them back to the server.

My c# code:

```
    hidden3 = new HtmlInputHidden();
    hidden3.ID = "total";
    hidden3.Value = index.ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(hidden3);
```

my javascript code:

```
     mod = document.getElementById("total");
     mod.value = newVal;
```

I can call the value back fine but it doesn't change.  I have also added alerts for the original value and then the value after changing values and they both show up fine.  However the code is never changed so when I pull the values

To get the value back I am using this;

```
    HtmlInputHidden hiddenControl = (HtmlInputHidden)FindControl("total");
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing it for a postback. Can you post your page code? Regards

Comment: How are you trying to "call the value back"? Are you using `Request["total"]`, or are you are dynamically adding back the hidden inputs, then trying to pull the value from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These controls are dynamically created and they have to be created in each postback. However, these should be built before Page_Load preferably in Page_Init event handler. If these are created in Page_Load, the view state has already been processed and the control can't be set from the posted value.

Comment: Where are you creating these controls?

Comment: Page_Load, I create them with a table that i use so I only have to query the database once.

Comment: Move the create code in Page_Init. Take a look at the article http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/06/26/123391.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that the resulting input tag as the ID of "total"? By default, in Webforms, the actual client-side ID is prefixed with the parent's Id (and a delimiting character); this helps to ensure that IDs are unique. One way to get the real client-side Id is to pull the value from the ClientID property of the control, but you should only look at that value once it has been put in a Controls collection.

Comment: Brian is right. If you are using ASP.NET 4.0, you can set ClientIDMode = "Static", so that the id remains as "total"

Comment: I was able to get the value using alert(document.getElementById("total").value); but i will try that out anyways