# How can i insert value to textarea from variable using attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to jQuery and i'm having a little problem i cant solve.
i tried to find a solution on google but with no success.

i want to insert value to textarea as a variable.
its inserting "facebook", instead of "hhhh".

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var facebook = "hhhh";
    $('#htmlcode').val($(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
});
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nv9xmzoq/4/

edit:
i have two buttons and i want to change the value according to their id

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing input value using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232747/changing-input-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `facebook` variable to `.val` method, like this

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var facebook = "hhhh";
    $('#htmlcode').val(facebook);
    return false;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nv9xmzoq/1/)

If you need set id also, you can do like this,

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var facebook = "hhhh";

    $(this).attr('id', facebook);
    $('#htmlcode').val(facebook);
    return false;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nv9xmzoq/6/)

**Update**

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var data = {
        facebook: "hhhh",
        twitter: "aaaa"
    };

    $('#htmlcode').val(data[$(this).attr('id')]);
    return false;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nv9xmzoq/9/)

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use to insert content

```
$('#htmlcode').val("something");
```

use to add atribute. ex:

```
$('#htmlcode').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

use to add or modify css

```
$('#htmlcode').css("width","500px");
```